# How to convert DriveInfo[] to List<string> C#

Tags: c#, driveinfo

hi I want to convert DriveInfo type list to string type list with using loop.In my code I am trying to use ToList() but it's not exist.
actually I want all the paths of logical drives in string list without using loop.
I know manually it's possible to use loop but I want to do this with direct function.
Thank.

here's my code

```
DriveInfo[] Drive_info = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

List<string> list = Drive_info.ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
DriveInfo[] Drive_info = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

List<string> list = Drive_info.Select(x => x.RootDirectory.FullName).ToList();
```

If I'm not wrong it takes path to all drives. Using select you can make new IEnumerable from property you choose. Using ToList() will convert to list.

Comment: good but working under .net frame work 3.5 not in lower version.

Comment: @user2713226 OP does not specified version of .net, so I supose he is using (or he can use) the newest version

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> list = Drive_info.Select (d => d.Name).ToList()
```

Comment: `ToList<string>()` instead of that you can write `ToList()`